# Security threats related to scripts simulating user actions

Tags: javascript, security

[MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) for `KeyboardEvent` states that

> Manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the browser itself.

And that's the reason why e.g. dispatching a `keyDown` `KeyboardEvent` doesn't actually enter they key in an input field.

I'm wondering what those "security reasons" are. Let's say I'm running a script in your site. I can already read and write the value at any `input` element. Then, what attacks is this preventing?

Comment: I think "interact with the browser itself" mean eg injecting a ctrl+v to read an user's clipboard.

Comment: or pressing enter to accept a "allow access to microphone" dialog, and probably lots of other things